# Why do the labels of the legend collide at the end of the lines in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggplotly

How can I put labels of the legend at the end of each line in ggplot?
The two labels of the legends overlap.
`geom_text` hasn't got the right `group` parameter probably.

```r
df <- structure(list(Epreuve = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "CE", class = "factor"),     Country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,     1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Country1",     "Country2"), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(18779,     18779, 18809, 18809, 18840, 18871, 18871, 18901, 18901, 18932,     18962, 18962, 18993, 19024, 19024, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144,     19144), class = "Date"), moyenn_gliss = c(55, 62, 47.5, 68.5,     44.6666666666667, 36, 45.6666666666667, 38, 25, 41.6666666666667,     48.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 52, 45.6666666666667,     25, 34, 23.3333333333333, 17.6666666666667, 25.3333333333333,     51.6666666666667), nb_total = c(250L, 38L, 250L, 38L, 250L,     250L, 38L, 250L, 38L, 250L, 250L, 38L, 250L, 250L, 38L, 250L,     250L, 250L, 250L, 38L), grp = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L,     4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse); library(plotly)
p <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Month, moyenn_gliss, color = interaction(Country, Epreuve, drop = T, sep = " "))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size =  size_pt <<- grp)) + geom_line(aes(size = size_pt * 0.7)) + 
  # The following geom_text does not produce the desired output
  geom_text(aes(x = last(unique(Month)), y = last(moyenn_gliss), label = paste(Country, Epreuve), color = interaction(Country, Epreuve, drop = T, sep = " "))) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(df$Month), date_labels="%b %y")

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column "label" which has the label for each group at the latest date like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
p <- df %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(Month == max(Month), paste(Country, Epreuve), NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, moyenn_gliss, color = interaction(Country, Epreuve, drop = T, sep = " "))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size =  size_pt <<- grp)) + 
  geom_line(aes(size = size_pt * 0.7)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label, y = moyenn_gliss + 2), size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(df$Month), date_labels="%b %y")

ggplotly(p)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Good. Now do you know how to make it with the `directlabels` package ?

Comment: @Julien, If you change the `geom_text` line with `geom_dl` from `directlabels` it returns the following warning: `Warning messages:
1: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[2L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_GeomDl() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues`. So it seems not possible at the moment.

Comment: Yes I got the same message